# click event not firing on elements inside thickbox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress, thickbox

In my wordpress plugin I am using thick box modal window to show the list of items. The content in the thickbox div is generated through a ajax request. I have input checkboxes inside this div. The click event on these check boxes are not triggered.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="wpb_media_tracks_container">    //This div is loaded into the thickbox and its contents are dynamically generated through ajax request
    <table class="wp_media_tracks_table">   
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Choose tracks</th>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td scope="row">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="1522" value="1522">
                </td>
                <td>raagrang.mp3</td>
                <td>raagrang</td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.wp_media_tracks_table input').on("click", function() {

    postId = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(postId);
});
```

I also tried using this selector: jQuery('#wpb_media_tracks_container input'). But no results.

Can any one help me find the issue in my code?

Edit:

More details:

Here is 'a' element which calls the thickbox to load the div with id=wpb_media_tracks.

```
<a href="#TB_inline?width=800&height=550&inlineId=wpb_media_tracks" class="thickbox">Add Tracks</a>
```

And I have set the div#wpb_media_tracks to display: none; (So that it is only displayed inside the thickbox modal).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since the div is loaded via ajax, this `jQuery('.wp_media_tracks_table input')` will not be recognized. You must get the parent of `div#wpb_media_tracks_container` which is existing DOM (not loaded via ajax), to attach event listener.

For e.g. `div#thickbox` is the parent that containing `div#wpb_media_tracks_container`, this one should work `$('div#thickbox').on('click', 'input', function() { ... });`

Comment: Thanks! But the solution did not work. I have div with class="inside" which is wrapped around the whole content. I tried this: jQuery('.inside input'). But did not work.

Comment: @Mr.code892 try `jQuery(document).on('click','.wp_media_tracks_table input',function(){});`

Comment: @Mohit I tried it. Also tried this : jQuery('document').delegate(".wp_media_tracks_table input", "click", function() {...

Comment: @Mr.code892 don't enclose document in qutos like `'document'`

Comment: @Mohit Thanks a lot. That worked. Not sure how I missed it. This is working for me 
 jQuery(document).on("click", "#wpb_media_tracks_container input", function() {